# Win 10 Regedit gives UAC message

Tags: windows-10

This is a recent change. If I try to run Regedit (via Win 10 Run box) I get this message:

[image]

I'm also getting it for a few other programs that never used to be a problem, but it seems particularly absurd that an MS program built into Win 10 Pro should display it.

Anyone know how I might fix it please?

Note: My UAC setting is on the third option, i.e. one above totally OFF.

Comment: Regedit has been subject to elevation since at least Windows 7.

Comment: It is not "absurd" but your misunderstanding. This changes isn't recent but it works since Vista. You running a tool that can easily destroy the whole system and M$ after failing many years behind more stable unix base OSes in sense of security finally start implementing the same mechanism. If you'd like to return in windows 95 era, then just turn off UAC completely. If you have some program that asking UAC prompt - it either written by non educated people or such program really need administrative privileges that need permission to run by real human to prevent malware to run it at will.

Comment: "it seems particularly absurd that an MS program built into Win 10 Pro should display it." - **Any** program that requires it's permissions to be elevated will display the UAC prompt.  "My UAC setting is on the third option, i.e. one above totally OFF." - It's not actually possible to disable UAC in Windows 8+.  Additionally, by setting UAC to the setting you have it at, you have disabled ALL UWP including programs like `Settings`.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong. click Yes to launch the utility.

Please understand, that unless you are coming from Windows XP, UAC is nothing new, so in many ways your incredulity hearkens back to this original argument, circa 2006 with the release of windows Vista. At this point, its pretty played out, and is probably one of the most extensively documented disagreements in the history of mankind, since it all occurred online. Needless to say, none of us want to talk about it anymore.

UAC functions in most ways like any other admin elevation scheme, like `sudo` or gksu/kdesu in Unix and Linux. While there were a few kinks with vista driver installs (primarily for ancient printers) and runas command support, UAC hasn't been a controversy since 2009 or so, as Win7 does a pretty good job with it (and everyone's late 90's hardware was long dead).

Any mainstream OS provides a similar functionality (most by default), so this isn't really worth discussing, beyond that nothing is wrong with your system, so don't sweat it.